# How can I have document flow ignore scale property?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'd like to implement a fly-in animation in CSS by having a particular block be scaled from 10 to 1.

However, if I apply the scaling, then a (horizontal) scroll bar appears:

https://jsfiddle.net/r2a5w7fo/15/

```css
body
{
  font: 10svw sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#zoom
{
  color: gray;
  scale: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This is a test line.
    </p>
    <p id="zoom">
      This is a zooming test line.
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a test line.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I keep scaling from influencing document flow? I want document scrollbars to behave as if scale always equaled "1".

Comment: You need to make sure the containing parent clips the scale overflow with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: I wouldn't want to do this as I want the original document to scroll as usual, including all necessary scrollbars, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a max-width property to the body

```
body
{
  font: 10svw sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and added your code to the above JsFiddle example, but it didn't work, I'm afraid.